# How to disconnect a single process from a shared memory object

Tags: c

So I have an assignment to create a library of functions that can create a posix shared memory table, add a record, delete a record and close the table. For the close_table function my prof wants it to only disconnect the current process calling close_table, so if there are two or more processes connect to the shared memory, only the one that called close_table will be disconnected. Looking at the different functions for working with posix shared memory it seems shm_unlink is the only thing that does something like that, except is deletes the shared memory object itself. is there a function that only disconnects only the process calling it?

```
/* Close connection to the given table.  This should only disconnect
 * the current process from the table.
 */
void close_table(table_t *tbl);
```

Comment: [`close(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/7/shm_overview)?

Comment: You just `munmap()` it.

Comment: but dont you call munmap() when youre unlinking the shared memory object?

Comment: @Abe The `munmap()` call does not have any effect on the underlying object (which is usually just a file).  Just as `shm_open()` creates the object, but not the mapping itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [POSIX `shm_open()` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_open.html), the creation of the shared memory region is:

```
fd = shm_open("/myregion", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
if (fd == -1)
    /* Handle error */;


if (ftruncate(fd, sizeof(struct region)) == -1)
    /* Handle error */;


/* Map shared memory object */


rptr = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct region),
       PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

To remove the mapping:

```
munmap( rptr, sizeof(struct region));
```

That's all that's needed.

You should have probably closed the file descriptor after calling `mmap()` as it's no longer needed or even very useful at that point.

Comment: ahh i think I was confused by the munmap() function. thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Abe Don't overthink POSIX "shared memory".  It's just another `mmap()`'d file.  See https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/posix/shm_open.c for the Linux implementation of `shm_open()`.  Normally the file is in `/dev/shm`, if I remember correctly, which is normally a `tmpfs` filesystem, which means the files are actually just in memory.